# Working code on Pycharm doesn't behave the same from Linux platform

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm running the following code.

My question is : why it's working from Pycharm under Windows OS, while nothing is printed out from the **3 tentative** @  *handleClickGroupButton*(self, button_id) when running from Linux (arm Raspberry) ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys

W_WIDTH = 400
W_HEIGHT = 250
W_X = 400
W_Y = 150


class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.zelabel = QLabel("")
        self.group_button = QButtonGroup()
        self.init()

    def init(self):

        self.group_button.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.handleClickGroupButton)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        buttons_list = ['btn1', 'btn2', 'btn3']

        positions = [(i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(4)]

        for position, name in zip(positions, buttons_list):
            if name == '':
                continue
            button = QPushButton(name)
            self.group_button.addButton(button, position[1] )
            grid.addWidget(button, *position)
            print ("position", position[1])

        grid.addWidget(self.zelabel)

        self.setWindowTitle("Some application ")
        self.show()

    def handleClickGroupButton(self, button_id):
        QtCore.qDebug("handle:" +  str(button_id))
        print("handle:", str(button_id))
        self.zelabel.text= ("handle:" + str(button_id))

        for btn in self.group_button.buttons():
            if btn is self.group_button.button(button_id):
                self.zelabel.setText("Clicked Button: " + btn.text() + str(button_id))




app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainFrame()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I do not reproduce the problem under Linux. Are you running the code from a terminal or from an IDE? Besides, you don't need to cycle through all buttons to get the clicked one: just use [`button(id)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#button), or alternatively use the default behavior of `buttonClicked` (without the overload, which is obsolete and should be avoided anyway, as the specialized `idClicked` signal should be used instead) and if you actually need the `id`, use [`id(button)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#id).

Comment: @musicamante : the linux app is called from terminal from the PI/Ubuntu (through VNC).
Thanks for the advice about button(id)

Answer (score 0):

For future readers with the same issue, here is how I resolved this:

1. I've removed the automatic desktop start ( through *raspi-config* )
2. then I've tried to start my app from the console which gave me this error :
   " *qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found*".

The [answers from the Qt forum could give you some clue](https://forum.qt.io/topic/93247/qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-though-it-was-found/115)  but in my case the libxcb was installed and symlinks too. Finally, I've found that the solution is basically simple, just start your application with:

```
    startx ./myapp.py
```

Then I've got my application running the good way, which is different from **running it from the desktop terminal**